# How to convert a vocal tract constriction variables (TVs) values to articulation features

Tags: articulation

I'm reading about [TVs](http://web.jhu.edu/cogsci/templates/images/pdf/people/gafos_dissertation-chapter_01.pdf) and I'm trying to figure out, how to convert their values to the corresponding articulation features like stop, palatal, unvoiced, bilabial, etc. Are there any ranges of values where the map is done? For instance, the perfect scenario for me will be something like this (arbitrary theory):

For TTCL, we know that the max and the min are 80 and 0 degrees respectively. In addition, for TBCL, we know that the max and the min are 180 and 87 degrees respectively. So, if TTCL ranges from 80 to 70 degrees and TBCL ranges from 180 to 170 degrees,  then we have a palatal articulatory feature.

Are there any such researches have been done that show something like this?